# How to inject this dependency in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I am having diffculty injecting this dependency: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/2.0.0-beta.10/src/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect.js into my project.

Here is the dependency injection scheme used in the project:

```js
 angular.module("myModule").controller("myController", MyController);

    function MyController($scope, $window, angular-js-dropdown-multiselect ){
    
    }
     MyController.$inject = ["$scope", "$window", "angular-js-dropdown-multiselect"]
```

However angular throws a Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider error.

I've tried changing angular-js-dropdown-multiselect to angularJsDropdownMultiselect but still see the error.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: It all starts with `angular-js-dropdownMultiselect` being a syntax error

Comment: Respect JS sintax.

Comment: fixed the typo on my part. Still have the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to inject a module as opposed to a provider.  Include that script on your page and inject whatever providers that module exposes.

Looking at that file, it doesn't expose anything but a directive, so just do something like the following:

JS:

```
angular.module('yourMoudule', ['angularjs-dropdown-multiselect'])
```

Usage:

```
<div dm-dropdown-static-include>...</div>
```

Comment: Took me awhile to figure out I needed to make your change at the top level of the application - not the controller...Thanks!